# What is SE policy regarding potentially offensive screen names?

Tags: discussion, support, display-names, offensive, faq-proposed

A user has chosen a screen name that could be construed as deeply offensive. Actually, aside from the possibility that it is intended as a joke (ie tongue-in-cheek), it can't be regarded as other than offensive.

What is SE policy on handling of such a case?

Comment: @Journeyman think we need to have a canonical answer first, before making a question candidate for faq. The answer here is good, but not canonical. :/

Comment: What would make it canonical tho?

Comment: @Journeyman now after the edit it's better, but still feels lacking, I'll try to think how it can be improved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a user - flag it, and a moderator will take a look. The local moderators will judge the username and reset it if needed. It’s also likely the user will get a moderator message explaining why, and if we're feeling nice, we may help reset it to something more appropriate. If you feel additional context is needed - either because it’s slang or not in English, please include as much as possible in the flag.

There may be slight delays while a moderator looks at the flag and decides what to do, but in general this is the workflow we follow. If there are doubts to the offensiveness, especially when it’s a non-English language or we aren't sure if it’s against policy, we may consult with staff or in some cases other moderators to work out the best solution.

Comment: Another case: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/128481/ching-chong-bing-bong?tab=profile "About me" and "Location" also contained offensive messages (now edited).